# long scheduler Delay in Spark UI

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn

i am running pyspark jobs on a 2.3.0 cluster on yarn.
i see that all the stages have a very long scheduler Delay.
BUT - it is just the max time, the 75th precentile is 28ms ....
all the other time metric are very low (GC time, task desirialization , etc.)
almost no shuffle write size.
the locality changes between mostly node local , process local and rack local.
what can be the reason for such long scheduler delay time ?
is it yarn or just missing resources to run the tasks ?
will increasing/decreasing partitions help this issue ?

Answer (score 3):

answering my own question in case somebody has the same issue - appeared to be related to skewed data that caused long delays . that was caused by using coalesce instead of repartition of the data , that divided the data unevenly.
on top of that i also cached the data frame after partitioning , so the processed ran locally(process_local) and not node_local and rack_locak.